# Spring 4 javaconfig for jasypt and profile

Tags: spring, jasypt, spring-java-config

How to convert below 2 xml configuration into java Config in Spring 4

1) jasypt

```
<encryption:encryptor-config id="eConf" password-env-name="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" algorithm="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />

<encryption:string-encryptor id="stringEnc" config-bean="eConf" />
```

first part (`encryption:encryptor-config`) of encryption could be converted like this:

```
@Bean
public EnvironmentStringPBEConfig environmentVariablesConfiguration() {

    EnvironmentStringPBEConfig config = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
    config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    config.setPasswordEnvName("APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD");
}
```

but, how to convert encryption:string-encryptor part.

2) profile

```
    <beans profile="dev">
        <util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:dev.properties" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:prod.properties" />
    </beans>
```

`@PropertySource("classpath:prod.properties")` is used for `util:properties`, but how to mention profile in the PropertySource annotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the source code of jasypt library ([EncryptionNamespaceHandler](https://github.com/vivosys/jasypt/blob/master/jasypt-spring31/src/main/java/org/jasypt/spring31/xml/encryption/EncryptionNamespaceHandler.java) and [EncryptorFactoryBean](https://github.com/vivosys/jasypt/blob/master/jasypt-spring31/src/main/java/org/jasypt/spring31/xml/encryption/EncryptorFactoryBean.java)) and the API for [PooledPBEStringEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/PooledPBEStringEncryptor.html) I'm assuming you can start experimenting with something like this:

```
@Bean
public EnvironmentStringPBEConfig environmentVariablesConfiguration() {
   EnvironmentStringPBEConfig config = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
   config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
   config.setPasswordEnvName("APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD");
   return config;
}
@Bean
public PooledPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor() {
   PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
   encryptor.setConfig(environmentVariablesConfiguration());
   return encryptor;
}
```

One note, though: I don't know anything about Jasypt, but I see their package names and documentation and everything is around spring 2, 3 and 3.1. Nothing about Spring 4. So, I don't say it won't work, but it is something to keep in mind in case things that look like they should work, but they don't.

As for `@PropertySource` I think you need something around these lines:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(value="prod")
@PropertySource("classpath:prod.properties")
public class ProdPlaceholderConfig {
...
}

@Configuration
@Profile(value="dev")
@PropertySource("classpath:dev.properties")
public class DevPlaceholderConfig {
...
}
```